# When does every compact $A$ in a topology satisfy $A⊆B⊆C$ for some open $B$ and compact $C$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space such that for any compact subset $A$ of $X$, there exists open set $B$ and compact set $C$ such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$. Does this property have a name? If so, what is it? Does this property hold for all topologies? If so I would like a proof and if not a counter example. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should change "all" with "every" in the question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This condition is a stronger version of one form of [local compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) (which considers the case that $A$ is a point); maybe it's equivalent to local compactness under some mild hypotheses, I don't know. In any case it implies local compactness (at least if we also assume that the space is Hausdorff so that all the usual definitions are equivalent), so any non-locally compact space is a counterexample and these are plentiful.

For an explicit counterexample consider any infinite-dimensional [normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) in the norm topology. By [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) we know that the closed unit ball is not compact; this implies that no open subset is contained in a compact subset.

Comment: If “compact” does not imply Hausdorff, then the given property is indeed equivalent to the variant where sets $A$ considered are singletons (finite union of compact subsets is compact).

Comment: @user87690: That also depends on the definition of "locally compact". OP's condition holds for compact spaces, but not all compact spaces are locally compact in the sense that every point has a local base of compact neighbourhoods. The two are definitely equivalent for Hausdorff spaces, though.

Comment: @tomasz: Yes, that's why I've described the property without calling it “locally compact”.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if the property has a name, but it doesn't have to hold even for metric spaces. Consider $X=\mathbb{Q}$ with the Euclidean topology and let $A=\{0\}$. Clearly no open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ is relatively compact (which is the same claim for metric, or even Hausdorff, spaces).

> **Lemma.** If $X$ is Hausdorff then the property is equivalent to [local compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space).

*Proof.* Note that for Hausdorff spaces the property "$V$ is contained in a compact set" is equivalent to "$\overline{V}$ is compact" which is also know as "$V$ is relatively compact".

"$\Rightarrow$" Since $\{x\}$ is compact then by our property it has open neighbourhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact. Hence local compactness.

"$\Leftarrow$" Let $A\subseteq X$ be compact. Then for any $x\in A$ there is an open neighbourhood $U_x\subseteq X$ of $x$ that is relatively compact. Since $\{U_x\}_{x\in A}$ cover $A$ then by compactness $A$ is covered by $U_{x_1},\ldots,U_{x_n}$. Clearly $U_{x_1}\cup\cdots\cup U_{x_n}$ is the neighbourhood we are looking for. $\Box$

For non-Hausdorff spaces I suppose we can treat the property as one of the many non-equivalent definitions of local compactness. The name looks appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The rationals with their usual topology are a counterexample. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb Q$. If $U$ is an open nbhd of $K$ in $\Bbb Q$, $\operatorname{cl}U$ is not compact, so $U$ is not contained in any closed subset of $\Bbb Q$. (To see that $\operatorname{cl}U$ is not compact, just note that it contains a non-degenerate interval in $\Bbb Q$.)

Answer (score 0):

As Qiaochu Yuan indicated, the property you described requires in particular that each point $x\in X$ have a compact nbhood; that is, the space is [**weakly locally compact**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/weakly_locally_compact).  It's the weakest form of local compactness, condition (1) in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space).

Weak local compactness is also sufficient to satisfy your condition.  To see this, adapt the argument from freakish.  Suppose $A$ is a compact set in $X$.  For each $a\in A$ choose a compact nbhood of it.  The interiors of these compact nbhoods from an open cover of $A$.  So $A$ can be covered by a finite number of these interiors.  And the finite union of the corresponding nbhoods is compact.  That gives you $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ with $B$ open and $C$ compact.

You can find many examples of spaces that are or are not weakly locally compact in [pi-base](https://topology.pi-base.org).  See [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000023/spaces) in particular.